# Activity crashes after button click

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I currently have this in and android activity but when the button is clicked the application crashes. I cant find what;s wrong.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private ListView recipes;
Intent intent;
Button button;
EditText input;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.searchlist);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeName);

    //recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
    //recipes.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.main, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.BaconSandwich)));
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View clicked) {
    if(clicked.getId() == R.id.submit) {
        //recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.array.recipes);
        String value = input.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
        SearchActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }
}

}
```

The activity is set in the android manifest and the next activity is blank
The log cat message I get is:

Error in RecipeMethodActivity onCreate().

My RecipeMethodActivity is:

```
package com.finalyearproject.cookmefood;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RecipeMethodActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the rest of your logcat?

Comment: Seems like the problem is in the next activity, can you post the onCreate of `RecipeMethodActivity`?

Comment: Alex just running the emulator again. But it just says where the problem is and it is apparently on the line. setContentView(R.layout.main); but I know this works on another activity.

Comment: What kind of error? NPE?

Comment: add a `try {} catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}` and read the error message.

Comment: Got it working finally but now I have the problem of it being in a tab host and when the new activity is created the tabs are removed. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

---

i checked your code..

see below

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button button;

private EditText input;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipeName);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.submit) {
            //recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.array.recipes);
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RecipeMethodActivity.class);
            DemoActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recipeName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

RecipeMethodActivity

`package com.Demo;`

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RecipeMethodActivity extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

}
```

}

new_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/@android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".DemoActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RecipeMethodActivity"></activity>
</application>
```